# WINAPI prevent my window from flickering?

Tags: c++, winapi, draw

I'm having a problem with my C++ WINAPI code, and as the title suggests, my window, when I redraw it, flickers.

Here's my code:

```
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <thread>
  #include <chrono>
  #include <mutex>

  #define TM_REDRAW 0x21

  static HICON hIconLarge, hIconSmall;
  static int i=55+75;

  void CALLBACK disegnaIcona(LPCSTR, HDC, DWORD, DWORD);
  void CALLBACK drawBitmap(LPCSTR, HDC, DWORD, DWORD);


  void WINAPI CALLBACK sfondo(HDC hdc) {
    drawBitmap(TEXT("Images\\Layout\\background.bmp"), hdc, 0, 0);
    drawBitmap(TEXT("Images\\Layout\\scacchiera.bmp"), hdc, 350, 10);
    }

    static void WINAPI CALLBACK piazzaPezzi(HDC hdc, HWND hwnd) {
    //disegna Ic0na = draw Icon
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Torre.ico"), hdc, 399, 55);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Cavallo.ico"), hdc, 399+73+1, 55);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Torre.ico"), hdc, 400+7*73+4, 55);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\TorreNero.ico"), hdc, 400+7*73+7, 55+7*75-11);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\TorreNero.ico"), hdc, 402, 55+7*75-11);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\CavalloR.ico"), hdc, 399+6*73+5, 53+1);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\CavalloRNero.ico"), hdc, 399+6*73+5, 55+7*75-7);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\CavalloNero.ico"), hdc, 399+73+2, 55+7*75-10);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Alfiere.ico"), hdc, 399+2*73+1, 55+1);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Alfiere.ico"), hdc, 399+5*73+5, 55+1);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\AlfiereNero.ico"), hdc, 399+2*73+2, 55+7*75-10);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\AlfiereNero.ico"), hdc, 399+5*73+5, 55+7*75-10);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Re.ico"), hdc, 399+3*73+1, 52+1);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\ReNero.ico"), hdc, 399+3*73+2, 55+7*75-10);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Regina.ico"), hdc, 399+4*73+1, 52+1);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\ReginaNero.ico"), hdc, 402+4*73+2, 55+7*75-10);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Pedone.ico"), hdc, 400, 53+75);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Pedone.ico"), hdc, 400+2*73, 53+75);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Pedone.ico"), hdc, 400+4*73+2, i);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Pedone.ico"), hdc, 400+6*73+2, i);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Pedone.ico"), hdc, 400+1*73, 53+75);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Pedone.ico"), hdc, 400+3*73, 53+75);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Pedone.ico"), hdc, 400+5*73, 53+75);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\Pedone.ico"), hdc, 400+7*73+6, 53+75);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\PedoneNero.ico"), hdc, 400+6*73+7, 53+6*75-6);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\PedoneNero.ico"), hdc, 400+4*73+7, 53+6*75-6);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\PedoneNero.ico"), hdc, 400+2*73+7, 53+6*75-6);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\PedoneNero.ico"), hdc, 400, 53+6*75-6);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\PedoneNero.ico"), hdc, 400+73, 53+6*75-6);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\PedoneNero.ico"), hdc, 400+3*73+7, 53+6*75-6);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\PedoneNero.ico"), hdc, 400+5*73+7, 53+6*75-6);
    disegnaIcona(TEXT("Pezzi\\PedoneNero.ico"), hdc, 400+7*73+7, 53+6*75-6);
    i++;
     }

   void CALLBACK drawBitmap(LPCSTR path, HDC hdc, DWORD xpos, DWORD ypos) {
    HBITMAP         bit;
    BITMAP          bitmap;
    HDC             hdcMem;
    HGDIOBJ         oldBitmap;
    bit      =      (HBITMAP)LoadImage (0, path, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);


    hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    oldBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, bit);

    GetObject(bit, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);
    BitBlt(hdc, xpos, ypos, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBitmap);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
   }

  void CALLBACK disegnaIcona(LPCSTR path, HDC hdc, DWORD xpos, DWORD ypos) {
HICON hIconLarge = (HICON) LoadImage( NULL, path, IMAGE_ICON, 72, 78, LR_LOADFROMFILE| LR_SHARED| LR_LOADTRANSPARENT| LR_DEFAULTSIZE);

DrawIconEx( hdc, xpos, ypos ,hIconLarge, 72, 78, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);
DestroyIcon(hIconLarge);    
 }

   LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {


switch(Message) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        SetTimer( hwnd, TM_REDRAW, 100, NULL );
    break;

    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        return true;
    break;

    case WM_PAINT:

    PAINTSTRUCT     ps;
    HDC             hdc;
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    sfondo(hdc);    // Sfondo = background
    piazzaPezzi(hdc, hwnd); // piazzaPezzi = draw pieces


    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;

    case WM_TIMER:
        RedrawWindow(hwnd, 0, 0, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY: {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }


    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}


 int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, char* lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
WNDCLASSEX wc;
HWND hwnd;
MSG msg;

memset(&wc,0,sizeof(wc));
wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);


wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.style        =  CS_SAVEBITS;

if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,"WindowClass","Caption",WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_MAXIMIZE,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 640, 480, NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);

if(hwnd == NULL) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return msg.wParam;
 }
```

What I thought to do was not to redraw the whole window, but just a section of it, the one where the change happens. Is it possible? if yes, how? otherwise how can I avoid flickering?

Thank you everybody.

Comment: It's a huge mistake to load the icons from disk every time you come to draw them. Before anyone spends anytime on this you should load the icons on startup, once only. Then see if that helps. Beyond that, the time is pointless. Remove it.

Comment: @David Herrernan: I'll try that, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really format your code like this?

Comment: @PreferenceBean This is not supposing to be a professional or team work, so yes, I did.

Comment: @Bafforasta: That's really not a good enough reason. Your code should be readable by default even when it's just for you. Get into the habit. And, let's not forget, you're asking _us_ to read it and fix it for free. It's not very polite to present unreadable code while doing so! I think then that you _are_ engaged in "team work" right now.

Comment: @PreferenceBean I'll do it then.

Comment: Intercepting WM_ERASEBKGND and leave the background of the window unpainted can produce pretty psychedelic effects.  I suppose it could look like flicker.  Writing code to double-buffer is work, you could let the OS take care of it by using the WS_EX_COMPOSITED window style flag.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Now it works much better, I wonder how I couldn't realize before, thanks!

Comment: If you really want to draw without flickering, create a Real-Time Message Loop (PeekMessage).

Comment: @Brandon if I try to use PeekMessage() instead of the classic GetMessage() my window suddently closes so I guess I'll have to keep that flicker (it doesn't bother too much). Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Bafforasta http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=9-1-4 Even though it says Direct-X, it's actually just WinAPI for that part. You need to do a while loop and then peek message. This is how OpenGL & Direct-X render so fast and without flickering (other than double buffering).

Comment: @Brandon In my PeekMessage() loop I first translate message and then dispatch it, but when I run my code it spawns and then immediately die.

Comment: @Brandon Your advice is terrible. No reason to believe that asker needs high frame rate. There's no animation here.